# Angular 8 / Ionic 5 / Openlayers 6 : Can't center map on feature

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, openlayers

I want to center an OL Map on a feature. This feature is referenced by a class property.

The method below is actually called when I click on the button used to trigger the centering, but the map doesn't move.

I've tried with Firefox and Brave, without success.
The map moved once though in FF but I modified something and can't get it to work again.

Here's my code (the commented lines are what I've also tried)

```js
    centerOnPosition() {
       var point: Point = <Point>this.positionFeature.getGeometry();
       console.log("Proj:", this.view.getProjection().getCode());
       console.log("actual center", this.view.getCenter());
       console.log("centering on pos", point.getCoordinates());
    
    this.view.setCenter( point.getCoordinates());
    // this.view.centerOn(point.getCoordinates(), this.map.getSize(),  [500, 500]);
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   this.map.updateSize();
    //   this.map.render();
    // }, 1000);
    //    this.map.getView().animate({
    //     center: point.getCoordinates(),
    //     duration: 1000
    //  })
    // this.map.updateSize();
    // this.view.setCenter( fromLonLat( point.getCoordinates() , get("EPSG:3857")));
    // this.map.render();
    }
```

Here's the output :

```
Proj: EPSG:3857 
actual center : Array [ 312807.60214986256, 5350017.244833869 ]
centering on pos : [ 6153873.7653989205, -2394513.7334693754 ]
```

EDIT : some more infos.

I'm suspecting badly projected coordinates. I got the position I want to center on with geolocation likewise :

```js
    var geolocation = this.initGeolocation();
    geolocation.setTracking(true);


     initGeolocation() {
     return new Geolocation({
       trackingOptions: {
         enableHighAccuracy: true,
       },
       projection: this.view.getProjection(),
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the problem was provoked by a piece of code in the component constructor : if the user wasn't authenticated, he was forwarded to the login page via a certain route.
(I tried to put this call on the ngOnInit and in ionViewWillEnter without success).

I don't totally get what's the issue, I guess the navigation change in the first access to the home page was messing with the map building... I will gladly accept an answer that will give my more insights.

Here the line of code I had to comment for now :

```js
   if (!this.accountService.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log("not logged !!");
      // this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu/login');
    }
```